# wp_query and comment_parent - select only posts with top level comments

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, comments, filters

I have a custom post type of 'films', and I'm creating a number of search filters using wp_query.  All are working fine, but I now need to add in an option of exclude results that dont have any *top level* comments.

I was hoping it would be as simple as:

```
   $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'films',
       'comment_parent' => 0
    );
```

But this still returns all results.
Is it possible to do what I want with wp_query?

EDIT

Here is my query so far.  It searches for the 'films' post type and filters based on genre.  Its a bit messy at the minute, but I just wanted to get everything working before tightening up the code.

```
   $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'films'
    );


    if(isset($_GET['g'])){
      $get_genres = $_GET['g'];

      $get_genres = array(
       'tax_query' => array(
            array(
               'taxonomy' => 'genre',
               'field' => 'id',
               'terms' => $get_genres,
               'operator' => 'IN'
            )
         )
      );


   $postsperpage = 10;
   $offset = $paged == 0 ? 0 : ($paged-1)*$postsperpage;

   $paging =   array(
      'posts_per_page' => $postsperpage,
      'offset' => $offset
   );

   $ordering =  array(
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC'
   );

   $args = array_merge($get_genres, $args);

   $args = array_merge($args, $ordering, $paging);  
   $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A post without a top level comment means it doesn't have any comments at all.  You can't query posts without comments unless you have a custom `$wpdb` query.

You can however run a check against the post to see if it has comments and then display it using `has_comments()` if the $wp_query object is set.

You can read more about the has comments function here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_comments

You could do a custom query like this:

```
if(!empty($_GET['no_comments'])){

  global $wpdb;

  $post_ids= $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE comment_count = %d AND post_type = %s", 0, 'films') );

   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'films',
    'post__in'    =>  $post_ids
   );

} else {

 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'films'
   );

}
```

This assumes you are using a form to choose whether or not to show posts with comments.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, that makes sense.  Do you know if it's possible to achieve what I'm after using a filter, similar to Brady's answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22949/query-post-by-title

Comment: Please post the full query you are using and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Will do.  I'll add it to the original question.  I'm a noob and its work in progress, so be gentle LOL

Comment: Chris see if this does the trick for you.

Comment: Thats perfect, Jacob. Thank you :) I came up with a similar solution (eventually), though not as tidy as your code.  But its good to know I was on the right track. Thanks again.

Comment: Only thing I changed was WHERE comment_count = to WHERE comment_count > i.e. to get only the posts that have comments.  Basically I'm using top level parent comments as reviews, and child comments as comments against the reviews.  Originally I thought I needed to distinguish between reviews and comments, but as its impossible to comment without there being a review, I only need to check for the comment count.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you.