# WP_Query returns more results than expected

Tags: wp-query

I've written a query that is supposed to return all attachments called "no-image" (is part of a function that handle images fallback when there isn't a featured image), the if I get some result, the function returns the first item.

Here's the code:

```
function misamee_get_image_placeholder($size, $icon = false, $attr = '')
{
    $transient_key = 'image_placeholder_id';
    $result = get_transient($transient_key);

    if (!$result || empty($result)) {
        $image_name = "no-image";

        $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'post_title' => $image_name
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($query_args);
        //echo '<pre>' . print_r($query, true) . '</pre>';

        if ($query->have_posts()) {
            $post = $query->posts[0];
            $result = $post->ID;
        }

        if ($result) {
            set_transient($transient_key, $result, CONTENT_CACHE_LIFETIME);
            return wp_get_attachment_image($result, $size, $icon, $attr);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that this query is clearly ignoring the "post_title" argument, returning all attachments, and therefore returning the last uploaded image (see the commented `echo '<pre>' . print_r($query, true) . '</pre>';`).

What it's wrong in my query?

Comment: [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) doesn't accept a `post_title` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `post_title` in [`WP_Query`'s parameter list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters). You need to use `name`, which accepts a *slug* not the actual post title.

> name (string) - use post slug.

It looks like all you are doing is getting an ID. That is a very heavy query if that is all you need. You can alter the parameters to lighten this up.

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => 1, // since you seem to be using only the first result
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, // don't juggle sticky posts to the top
    'no_found_rows' => true, // don't calculate total returns
    'name' => $image_name,
    'fields' => 'ids' // only return the post IDs
);
```

Comment: Thank you s_ha_dum!
I wonder why I can't query by post_title: I didn't notice that wasn't an option.

Also I appreciate your improvement advice to make the query lighter: I already save the result in a transient that expires each few minutes, but it's always good to improve the code :)

However, in some cases is not possible to edit the image slug (and I need to allow editors to set the "no-title" for any image I upload).

For anyone interested, here is a way to make WP_Query filter by post_title: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22949/query-post-by-title